# How to cancel AsyncTask when Activity finishes?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

In my Activity I use multiple AsyncTask classes.

How to cancel AsyncTask when Activity finishes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531336/asynctask-wont-stop-even-when-the-activity-has-destroyed

Comment: check this for a good example on correct way to cancel an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand if your "cancel" means rollback but you have a [cancel](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) method on the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.

Comment: After the task is finished I want it to disappear.

Answer (score 7):

i think the best place to do this is `onStop`

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    /*
    * The device may have been rotated and the activity is going to be destroyed
    * you always should be prepared to cancel your AsnycTasks before the Activity
    * which created them is going to be destroyed.
    * And dont rely on mayInteruptIfRunning
    */
    if (this.loaderTask != null) {
        this.loaderTask.cancel(false);
    }
}
```

in my Task i then check as often as possible if *cancel* was called

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    if (this.isCancelled()) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and of course dont forget to drop data that maybe returned since there's no more Activity to receive it

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<UserStatus> result) {
    if(!this.isCancelled()) {
        //pass data to receiver
    }
}
```

Comment: onPostExecute is never called with isCancelled is set to true. Instead a call is placed to onCancelled(Object)

Answer (score 2):

The asynctask thread is kept alive in a thread pool for future istances of AsyncTask. You can't remove them.

Comment: While this may be true, the question is about cancelling the task, not getting rid of its thread.

Comment: Note @Pentium10 comment in the accepted answer - He wants the "task" (I believe meaning "thread") to "disappear.  This is why I think this answer is best.