# How I can cancel the AsyncTask during invocation?

Tags: android

I am implementing a function which performs some backend database task. I have used Asynctask for that but If the backend task is in process and I close the activity, I want to cancel the AsyncTask too. How I can do tat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cancel AsyncTask when Activity finishes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533149/how-to-cancel-asynctask-when-activity-finishes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to cancel AsyncTask when Activity finishes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533149/how-to-cancel-asynctask-when-activity-finishes/2537088#2537088)