# app crashes when asynctask closed with no internet connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am trying out below code everything works fine when net is connected

here is the workflow

there is a main activity from where on button click this activity should open
it would  do the parsing part and then go  to next list activity.in case there is a back press or this activity is closed the asynctask should stop using

```
loader.cancel(true);
```

**this would work perfectly if net is available and tested the issue happens when dont have internet connection**

**the alert box shows and it goes to the first activity then it crashes**

i want the alert box to show and app should not crash and go back to first -->mainactivity

i have refereed this
http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

[How to end AsyncTask onBackPress()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783320/how-to-end-asynctask-onbackpress?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.parser.DOMParser;
import com.parser.RSSFeed;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    

    //private String RSSFEEDURL = "http://www.mobilenations.com/rss/mb.xml";
    RSSFeed feed;
    private AsyncLoadXMLFeed loader;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position =  i.getExtras().getInt("position");
        String[] country = i.getStringArrayExtra("country");
        
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null) {


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(
                    "Unable to reach server, \nPlease check your connectivity.")
                    .setTitle("TD RSS Reader")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Exit",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            //loader.cancel(true);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });


            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            
            alert.show();

        } else {
            // Connected - Start parsing

            loader = new AsyncLoadXMLFeed();
            loader.execute();
            //new AsyncLoadXMLFeed().execute();

        }

    }
    

    private class AsyncLoadXMLFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Obtain feed
            DOMParser myParser = new DOMParser();
            Intent i = getIntent();
            int position =  i.getExtras().getInt("position");
            String[] country = i.getStringArrayExtra("country");
            String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
            //feed = myParser.parseXml(RSSFEEDURL);
            feed = myParser.parseXml("http://"+name+".blogspot.com//feeds/posts/default/-/" + country[position] + "?alt=rss");

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("feed", feed);

            // launch List activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

            // kill this activity
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish(); 
    }
    
    @Override
       public void onDestroy(){
          super.onDestroy();

          // Cancel the task
          loader.cancel(true);
       }
```

Comment: post crash log with question

Comment: have You set permissions ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE ?

Comment: yes every thing works fine with net connection

Answer (score 0):

My guess it crashes with NullPointerException.

It is because if you don't have network connectivity you don't create `AsyncLoadXMLFeed` instance.
So when `onDestroy()` happened and you call `loader.cancel(true);` it throws this Exception.

Answer (score 0):

finally did this
thanks anatol needed to check **loader != null**

```
@Override
       public void onDestroy(){
          super.onDestroy();

          // Cancel the task
          if(loader != null && loader.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
              loader.cancel(true);
          }

          //loader.cancel(true);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest solution for handle this issue is that use **try catch block** in your **onPost execute()** in async task. like this

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(UserLogin.this, "Something is going wrong, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

simply this will prevent your app from crash.