# Android Why does my app Force to close?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I admit, I'm new at this whole Android stuff. I am trying to make an app but randomly I get Force close errors and I really don't know why. My application has many activities, none of them finish() when I start a new one. I get data from the web (via web services and direct image downloading) and I use AsyncTask a lot. Most of the time it crashes on the asynctask. Here is a sample on how I do things:

```
private BackTask backTask;
Activity ctx = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.trackslist);

        backTask = new BackTask();
            backTask.execute();
    }

    protected class BackTask extends AsyncTask<Context, String, myObject>
        {
            @Override
            protected myObject doInBackground(Context... params) 
            {
                 try{
                        if (hasInternet(ctx)==true)
                        {
                            //access the web SERVICE here
                        //initialize myObject WITH result FROM the web
                         return myObject
                       }
                       else
                       {
                            return null
                       }

                  }catch(Exception ex){
                       return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                    super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
            {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCancelled()
            {
                    super.onCancelled();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute( myObject result ) 
            {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    if (result==null || result.isEmpty())
                    {
                           //no valid result, show a message
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //result valid do something with it
                    }
            }
        }

     @Override
        public void onPause()
        {
            if (backTask!=null && ! backTask.isCancelled())
            {
                backTask.cancel(true);
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

    public void btnStartOnClick(View target) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class); 
      startActivity(intent);
 }
```

When the activity gets onPause() the task is being canceled. I am not sure what happens during the try/catch if a error appears, from what I've did, it should return null, but I think here I miss something. As I said before, randomly I get a force close even if I am on another Activity. This is really frustrating as I can't offer a app that has this behavior. So, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: if there's a FC, you should check the log ('adb shell logcat' in command line from sdk/tools directory; or in Eclipse DDMS view). Then paste the error log here.

Comment: I checked the log and variably it is null pointer exception in the asynctask... the thing is I'm on another activity when I get the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask inside your `AsyncTask` class for `isCancelled()` and then decide what to do.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531336/asynctask-wont-stop-even-when-the-activity-has-destroyed). It has a good explanation by Romain Guy:

> You can stop an AsyncTask. If you call
>   cancel(true), an interrupt will be
>   sent to the background thread, which
>   may help interruptible tasks.
>   Otherwise, you should simply make sure
>   to check isCancelled() regularly in
>   your doInBackground() method. You can
>   see examples of this at
>   code.google.com/p/shelves.

Answer (score 2):

There is problem in your code. I have corrected as follows: You find I have added **this** while calling async task.
Your async task accept context as argument and you was not passing that.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.trackslist);

     backTask = new BackTask();
     backTask.execute(this);
}
```

Comment: I never used execute(this). Curiously I didn't manage to find any info if it's requested or not. Could you please elaborate a little why is it necessary ? Thank you.

Comment: Alin, Its not necessary. You have defined Context as first parameter  "extends AsyncTask<Context, String, myObject>" so you need to pass it.  If you don't need to pass Anything then put there "Void" as first paramteter

Comment: I understand now, good point. Interesting that it works like it is. What happens in a try catch if something goes wrong ? Does it return null to onPostExecute ?