# Java: Force stopping of ExecutorService threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

My code:

```
String[] torrentFiles = new File("/root/torrents/").list();

        if(torrentFiles.length == 0 || torrentFiles == null)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        for(String torrentFile : torrentFiles)
        {
            ex.submit(new DownloadTorrent("/root/torrents/" + torrentFile));
        }

        ex.shutdown();

        try
        {
            ex.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex1)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
```

But sometimes torrent downloading takes unknown time value and «`awaitTermination`» not works as I want. I need to stop all executed threads instantly after half an hour but as I know «`awaitTermination`» just only use `interrupt()` method which works only in loops or waiting. So timeout not works if this moment happens. So, how to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` will try to stop all the executing threads..

Here is a quote from javadoc

> `List<Runnable> shutdownNow()`
>
> Attempts to stop all actively
> executing tasks, halts the processing
> of waiting tasks, and returns a list
> of the tasks that were awaiting
> execution.
>
> There are no guarantees
> beyond best-effort attempts to stop
> processing actively executing tasks.
> For example, typical implementations
> will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so
> if any tasks mask or fail to respond
> to interrupts, they may never
> terminate.

Comment: I am also using shutdownNow() to stop all the other executing threads but I am able to stop a thread which is waiting for a service response. If I put the thread to sleep then it stops it immediately but in the pervious case it doesn't. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: @Akshay - yes there is reason for that happening. Thread.sleep() checks for interruption status and if the thread is already interrupted , it then throws InterruptedException. However in absence of such blocking thing happening, as mentioned in doc , There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks

Answer (score 11):

Instant thread termination is never guaranteed, unless the thread checks periodically for isInterrupted() flag (or is waiting in interruptable method, i.e. which throws InterruptedException).

Consider implementing your worker threads in manner, when they check periodically for isInterrupted(). This may be something like that:

```
public void run() { 
  byte[] data;
  do {
     data = receiveDataChunk(timeout);
     processData(data);
  } while(!isInterrupted() && data != null);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since downloading a torrent probably involves blocking IO operations, simply calling `cancel()`/`shutdownNow()` won't be enough, because blocking IO operations are not guaranteed to terminate when their respective threads are interrupted.

You also need to close the underlying sockets in order to cancel blocking IO, see [How to terminate a thread blocking on socket IO operation instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425350/how-to-terminate-a-thread-blocking-on-socket-io-operation-instantly).

Answer (score 1):

[`ExecutorService.submit(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-) returns a `Future<?>` that has a `cancel()` method.  You should keep track of these can call it when you want each task to stop.

Comment: If he has not implemented a check on Thread.interrupted() in his implementation this will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Am Using this code i have created.

Its generating many pdf files from many html templates using **wkhtmltopdf** .

so i want to increase performance of creating handreds without keep client waiting, this is only one part of implementation.

About **getListOfCallables** its returning the correct optimal
threshold for # of threads to use in fixed pool creation.

So i cant handle having lots of un dead threads laying around it made my EC2
CPU 100% stuck.

I used :

- shutdown()
- shutdownNow() in else of await
- shutdownNow() in exception part

List fileGenerationHtmlToPdfList = getListOfCallables(paths, name, options);

```
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(fileGenerationHtmlToPdfList.size());


            List<Future<ArrayList<File>>> futures = null;

            try {
                futures = executorService.invokeAll(fileGenerationHtmlToPdfList);
                try {
                    for(Future f: futures) {
                        files.addAll((ArrayList<File>)f.get());
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted Exception " , ex);
                } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted Exception " , ex);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted Exception " , ex);
            }

 executorService.shutdown();//try shutdown

            try {
                if (executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Done ShutDowned");
                } else {
                    executorService.shutdownNow();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                executorService.shutdownNow();
                Logger.getLogger(FileUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Interrupted Exception " , ex);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Now I have to stop threads from a pool. I am doing it such a way. It may be not a good idea. Comment, please, if so.

```
boolean isTerminated = mPoolThreads.isTerminated();
while (!isTerminated) {
    mPoolThreads.shutdownNow();
    isTerminated = mPoolThreads.isTerminated();
    Log.i(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Stop threads: the threads are not terminated yet");
}
Log.w(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Stop threads: Terminated");
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the direct question, but instead of the `while` loop, a better pattern in such cases (where you can't tell from just looking at the code that it will terminate) is to say e.g. `for (int retries = 0; retries < 1000; ++retries)`. Also, add a 10 ms wait between retries, or at least [`yield()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6979859/1143274). If it reaches 1000, log an error. (Instead of 1000 it should be some large number that is entirely unreasonable to expect if it behaved correctly.)