# Difficulty with timer and threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Two threads start. I want to interrupt the first thread in 2 seconds.
What have I done wrongly with my timer? It seems to be not interrupting the thread.

```
class ThreadTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        firstThread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("firstThread has been terminated.");
    } // run
} // class ThreadTask

Timer timer = new Timer();
ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask();
timer.schedule(task, new Date().getTime() + 3000);
```

Comment: Where is "firstThread" defined? Perhaps you are simply not handling interruption properly. (Note that interruption is cooperative, so your other thread needs to check for interruption to exit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code to interrupt a thread.

Check for `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` in `Thread.run()` method.

`Timer` must be started from `Thread.run()` method if you want to interrupt it after 3 seconds from starting its execution.

```
    import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ThreadTimer implements Runnable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new ThreadTimer()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask(Thread.currentThread());
        timer.schedule(task, 3000);

        while (true) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(Math.random() * 1000);
            // do whatever you want to do here
        }
    }

}

class ThreadTask extends TimerTask {

    private Thread thread;

    public ThreadTask(Thread thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        thread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Thread has been terminated.");
    } // run
} // class ThreadTask
```

---

If above code doesn't fit as per you requirement then use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination()` as a best option to do this.

Here is a [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900387/how-to-stop-all-runnable-thread-in-java-executor-class?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is an error in the use of the method [Timer.schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29).

You are using:

> public void schedule(TimerTask task, long delay) Schedules the
>   specified task for execution after the specified delay. Parameters:
>   task - task to be scheduled. delay - delay in milliseconds before task
>   is to be executed.

If you take the current time + 2 seconds, then the thread will stop working through ~44 years.

Use:

```
timer.schedule(task, 3000);
```