# Stop all running threads in Java Executor Service

Tags: java, database, multithreading, executorservice

My goal is to listen to changes in 2 or more tables in a database. So I implemented one thread per table.
In this case to handle the threads I have used Executor Service.

I need to stop these running threads as per the request of the client side. Here is the current implementation.

```
public class TableListener extends Thread {

    private String prevName;
    private final String query;

    public TableListener(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(Settings.REFRESH.trim()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CommonDao commonDao = new CommonDao();
            String name = commonDao.loadTable(this.query);
            if(prevName != null && !prevName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("prevName: " + prevName + "name: " + name);
            } else {
                System.out.println("no changes");
            }
            prevName = name;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class TableListenerService{

    public static ExecutorService pool;

    public void initializeThreads() {
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        pool.execute(new TableListner("select * from person"));
        pool.execute(new TableListner("select * from demo"));
    }

    public void stop() {
        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted, so exiting.");
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            if (pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("task completed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Forcing shutdown...");
                pool.shutdownNow();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But when executing the stop method, it gets below error

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.example.demo.service.TableListner.run(TableListner.java:19)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.example.demo.service.TableListner.run(TableListner.java:19)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

could anyone support me in overcoming this and any optimized solution for this problem?

Comment: You haven't shown the `TableListener` class, which appears to be the one you're having trouble with. What's the relevance of the Runnable with the sleep?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. here I added the TableListener class. 
and I followed this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900387/how-to-stop-all-runnable-thread-in-java-executor-class

Comment: What do you expect calling `shutdownNow()` to do to each Thread? Why do you expect that to stop the Thread, given the implementation you've shown above?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812233/getting-events-from-a-database

Comment: (And you didn't answer either of my questions)

Comment: @tgdavies I am not much familiar with java Executor Service.
now the TableListener class has been added to the question description
I tried to stop currently executing tasks from calling shutdownNow()
so was expecting to stop the threads for stopping infinite loop inside the thread. (which is in the TableListener class)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java When you call `shutdownNow()`, `interrupt()` will be called on each Thread.