# Safe way to stop Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Can anyone explain to me why the first thread doesn't work and the second works perfectly:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        TestThread1 t1 = new TestThread1();
        TestThread2 t2 = new TestThread2();

        t1.startThread();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        t1.stopThread();
        t2.stopThread();
    }
}

class TestThread1 extends Thread {

    private volatile TestThread1 thread;

    public void startThread() {
        thread = new TestThread1();
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (thread != null) {
            System.out.println("RUNNING 1 ...");
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        thread = null;
    }
}

class TestThread2 extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean finished = false;

    public void run() {
        while (!finished) {
            System.out.println("RUNNING 2 ...");
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

When I debug inside `TestThread1` class: Inside `startThread`, the `thread` member is filled (so it is not `null`), inside `run`, `thread` member is `null`!!! And finally, inside `stopThread`, the `thread` member is not `null`!!!

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: You seem to be creating TWO instances of `TestThread1`, one in `main` and one in `startThread()`. `TestThread1#startThread()` should be just `this.start()`.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes that is what i want to do. i want to know why the second thread created inside the first object is null inside run method

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode `thread` is `null` until you call `startThread()` on it and you only do this for the first thread

Comment: Its working fine in both the cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, you have two instances of `TestThread1 t1`:

- One is stored into your `t1` local variable (in your `main` method).
- One is stored into your `thread` instance variable (of `t1`).

`t1` is never started, `t1.thread` is.

`t1.stopThread()` sets `t1.thread` to `null`, but it doesn't affect `t1.thread.thread`.

Since you're starting `t1.thread`, its `run` method is using `t1.thread.thread`:

- This is never set to anything (so it's using `null`).
- Calling `t1.stopThread()` like you do would only set `t1.thread` to `null`, which wouldn't affect `t1.thread.thread`.

---

More generally, you can't just "kill" a thread as such, but you can implement tests within the method to tell it to return under certain circumstances. What you've done with your second test is closer to this (using `while (!finished) { ... }` with a volatile variable).

I wouldn't limit the test to `finished`. It's also useful to test whether the thread was interrupted, in particular because if you run your runnables within an `ExecutorService` `shutdownNow()` will try to interrupt them (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5946647/372643)).

I'd use `while (!finished && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { ... }`.

(Note the difference between `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and `Thread.interrupted()`: they may seem similar, but the latter will also reset the status, which you might not want.)

Depending on what's within your loop (or whether there is a loop at all), you may want to use something like `if (finished || Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { return; }` at various strategic points, where it makes sense.

Comment: In the fact i wanted to implement ths solution to deprecated stop method which is explained in this page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: @Braj, what do you mean?

Comment: @Bruno can you look to the link i sent and help me to implement that solution please.

Comment: Have you tried it? It is stopped in both the cases.

Comment: @Braj, sure, `TestThread1` will not even enter its loop at any point: `t1.thread.thread` is always `null`, as I said.

Comment: The first thread can't enter to the loop because thread member is null.

Comment: @Bruno can you help to implement the solution explained in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html in the section What should I use instead of Thread.stop?

Comment: @Bruno But what i read is that working with interrupt flag is not good practice because that flag can be reset by any method which throw InterruptedException

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'd use both `finished` and check for interruption, and also catch and exit/re-interrupt when handling this exception.

Comment: @Bruno i understand, but my objective for using a thread member is that i want to set that thread member to null inside the stopThread because from what i read it's the best way to kill safely a thread.

Comment: @Bruno The second thread doesn't set the thread member to null (because it doesn't have one), so the thread instance will not be taken by the finalizer to liberate all resources allocated by the thread.

Comment: Why would you want a thread member within your thread (or runnable)? Losing a reference to a thread doesn't make it stop if it's still doing something. Not sure where you got your references from.

Comment: @Bruno According to this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html what i understand : to kill a thread correctly it should be set to null to avoid having damaged object, because having null object will liberate all resources allocated by the thread.

Comment: Just remembered this... You might be interested in [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/52454/9735). Getting the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
TestThread1 t1 = new TestThread1();
t1.startThread();
```

This will simply call method `startThread()` on object t1. Inside this method you are creating a new Thread.

```
thread = new TestThread1();
        thread.start();
```

But for this Thread `thread` instance variable is null(It is not null for t1).

So in both cases thread variable should be null.

Comment: the first thread is created and started inside the startThread method of TestThread1 class

Answer (score 0):

There is two TestThread1 object being created, one is started and the other is stopped.

I suggest not extending Thread and instead wrapping your Runnable once.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your main method you create a Thread1 Object. You then run startThread which creates a different Thread1 object inside the first one and sets it to the field thread. You then start the second object which didn't have its own thread field initialized. When run method is run on the second object the condition is false and the while loop doesn't start.

Your object hierarchy looks something like this

```
t1 (Thread1) {
    thread(Thread1): {
        thread: null;
        run() {
             while (thread != null) {...} // this is the method that is run - thread is null here since you never initialized it
        }
   };
   startThread() {} // calls the run method on the nested thread object above
   run() {
        while (thread != null) {...} // this method is not run since t1.start() is never called in main()
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, your are right man, i created second thread wishing to execute the run method of the first thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your case,

```
 t2.start();
```

is calling run method directly, it is not creating `thread` inside `startThread` method.

so `t1.stopThread()` makes the `volatile thread` inside `Thread1` class null. so you are getting like that.

solution

use

```
 t1.startThread();
        t2.startThread();
```

instead of

```
 t1.startThread();
        t2.start();
```

which  makes 2 threads to create separate threads inside that method.

if you want a single thread of Thread1 then use runnable interface and create 2 threads and call startThread respectively rather than creating extra threads inside main.