# Java threading, shutting down a server thread from a main JFrame GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I have a program that starts up a passive server that spawns a connection handler for each connection to the server socket. I would like to find an eloquent way to shutdown the server socket and release the port. Currently, I am not sure how to interrupt the `Socket.accept` method. I have been using a synchronized method to set a flag in another Thread, but `Socket.accpet` blocks until a connection is made.

My passive server code

```
package NetSecConsole;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class PassiveServer implements Runnable
{
    Thread runner;
    int port = 20000;
    MainFrame mainFrame;
    ServerSocket s = null;

    public PassiveServer(MainFrame mf, int hostPort) 
    {
        mainFrame = mf;
        port = hostPort;
        try 
        {
            s = new ServerSocket(hostPort);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            newStatus("Server [Constructor]: Could not open server socket! " + e);
        }
    }

    public void start() 
    {
        if (runner == null) 
        {
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            int connCount = 1;
            for (;;) 
            {
                // Sit and wait for a connection
                newStatus("Server [run]: Waiting for connection to port " + Integer.toString(port) + "...");
                Socket incomingConnection =  s.accept();

                // Pass the connection off to a connection handler thread
                newStatus("Server [run]: Got connection on port " + Integer.toString(port));
                final ConnectionHandler conHand = new ConnectionHandler(mainFrame, incomingConnection, connCount); 

                // Start the connection handler, then continue;
                conHand.start();
                connCount++;
            } 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            newStatus("Server [run]: IOException: "  + e);
        }
    }

    public final void newStatus(final String arg)
    {
        Runnable sendMsg = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                    mainFrame.newStatusLine(arg);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sendMsg);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to force an exception by closing the listening socket, (which is perfectly fine IME), then set a volatile boolean 'shutdown' flag that that is checked after every accept() return. Then make the accept() call return by opening a localhost client connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `interrupt` on the server/background thread or `close`
on the server socket. I didn't know about the latter, just Googled it.

See also:

[How to terminate a thread blocking on socket IO operation instantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425350/how-to-terminate-a-thread-blocking-on-socket-io-operation-instantly)

Answer (score 0):

You can call close() on the ServerSocket.  The pending accept call(s) with throw a SocketException, so you can trap that for a clean exit.