# IllegalMonitorStateException when using locks and conditions to pause/resume execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, locking

I am looking for a "better" way of pausing and resuming execution of worker threads' tasks.

Usually one would use a boolean flag such as an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to set a flag state which the worker threads check before a next iteration in their work.

Something like the code snippet below

```
    AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    Runnable r = () -> {
        while (true) {
            // check for pause
            while (!b.get()) {
                // sleep thread then check again
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // do work
        }
    };
    Thread p = new Thread(r);
    p.start();
```

This is certainly not an elegant solution, and for this reason I have been experimenting with locks and conditions.

Before jumping into my attempt at using locks & conditions, first we take a look at the examples and docs. I will be using a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and a [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) as my flag for pause/resume states in my [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) worker tasks.

**ReentrantLock**

Using [ReentrantLock.lock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#lock()) will pause execution of the current thread until the lock can be acquired, an alternative is [ReentrantLock.tryLock()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html#tryLock()) which allows us to acquire the lock if not held by another thread.

**Condition**

Condition by way of the example found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) allows one to signal another thread to either wait or continue with execution by either using [Condition.await()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await()) or [Condition.signal()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signal()) (or [Condition.signalAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#signalAll()) ), see below

**Problem:**

By Reviewing the documentation specifically for `Condition.await()` and the 4 conditions in which `await()` can be called, it leads me to believe that Condition can only be used to resume a task, not pause a task.

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:

> - Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or

This means I can call `condition.signalAll()` from my UI thread on a condition that is currently `await()`ing in a worker thread, thus scheduling it for execution. i.e. **Resume**

However I cannot see a way to arrive at this state i.e. **Pause** using conditions since for a condition to go into an await state, the documentation says:

> The **current thread is assumed to hold the lock associated with this Condition** when this method is called. It is up to the implementation to determine if this is the case and if not, how to respond. Typically, an exception will be thrown (such as **IllegalMonitorStateException**) and the implementation must document that fact.

---

**My test example using Android**

**Logic**

1. User clicks start button
2. Executor Thread Pool starts incrementing a counter (indefinitely) and displaying it on the UI (symbolizing a long running function)
3. User clicks pause button
4. Executor thread awaits for lock to be unlocked (where condition comes in)
5. User clicks resume button
6. Condition signaled, executor thread continues incrementing till stop/exit

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView lblCounter;
    private Button btnStartStop, btnPauseResume;

    private ReentrantLock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition waitCondition = pauseLock.newCondition();
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(4);

    private AtomicBoolean stopStart = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lblCounter = findViewById(R.id.counter);
        btnStartStop = findViewById(R.id.startStop);
        btnPauseResume = findViewById(R.id.pauseResume);

        btnStartStop.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (stopStart.get()) {
                start();
            } else {
                stop();
            }
        });

        btnPauseResume.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            pauseResume();
        });
    }

    public void start() {
        btnStartStop.setText("Stop");
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            while (true) {

                // here we check if the lock is locked, if so, we should wait await until a signal is emmited
                while (pauseLock.isLocked()) {
                    try {
                        waitCondition.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                int i1 = i.incrementAndGet();
                lblCounter.setText(String.valueOf(i1));
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop() {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        btnStartStop.setText("Start");
    }

    public void pauseResume() {
        if (pauseLock.isLocked()) {
            pauseLock.unlock();
            waitCondition.signal();
            btnPauseResume.setText("Pause");
        } else {
            pauseLock.lock();
            btnPauseResume.setText("Resume");
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:text="123"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pauseResume"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pause"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/startStop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/startStop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="96dp"
        android:text="Counter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

A problem with this code impl above is in the `while` loop before surround this `waitCondition.await();` I don't acquire a lock on `pauseLock`, thus when the user clicks the pauseResume button and I acquire a lock in `pauseResume()`, the worker thread executes the `waitCondition.await()` causing an exception below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
Process: nmu.wrpv302.myapplication, PID: 11744
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1291)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.fullyRelease(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1752)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2064)
    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.lambda$start$2$MainActivity(MainActivity.java:61)

        ^ --------------------- PROBLEM -----------------------

    at com.example.myapplication.-$$Lambda$MainActivity$te94WnCx7dwprXfxnjJZuoEc1_8.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1155)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1993)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1941)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

**Question:**

Using [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)s & [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)s, how can I improve on the standard boolean flag check + [thread.sleep()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) for worker threads to pause/resume execution

Answer (score 1):

I think that for your particular example of logic (to manage a counter) Conditions, Locks etc. seem to be overkill.

1. If we see this process as one single long living process, old good Object.wait()/notify()/notifyAll() with explicitly instantiated Thread should work just perfectly:

   ```
    final Object lock = new Object();

    AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    Runnable r = () -> {
        _end:
        while (true) {
            while (b.get()) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    break _end;
                }
                // increment the counter
            }
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (!b.get()) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break _end;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread p = new Thread(r);
    p.start();

    ...
    b.set(false); // disable
    ...
    synchronized (lock) {
        b.set(true); // enable
        lock.notify(); // to notify for enabled state change
    }
    ...
    b.set(false); // disable
   ```
2. ReentrantLock + Condition work exactly like Object.wait()/notify()/notifyAll() (inside synchonized block). All Condition's methods must be called when the current thread holds the lock, otherwise you get IllegalMonitorStateException (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html):

   ```
    final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition enabled = lock.newCondition();

    AtomicBoolean b = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    Runnable r = () -> {
        _end:
        while (true) {
            while (b.get()) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    break _end;
                }
                // increment the counter
            }
            lock.lock();
            try {
                while (!b.get()) {
                    try {
                        enabled.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break _end;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread p = new Thread(r);
    p.start();

    ...        
    b.set(false); // disable

    ...
    lock.lock(); // if you don't lock before signal, you get IllegalMonitorStateException
    try {
        b.set(true); // enable
        enabled.signal(); // to notify for enabled state change
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    ...
    b.set(false); // disable
   ```
3. We also can see the process as a sequence of increment tasks. In this case ExecutorService is a good choice. Just store the reference to your task to cancel it when required:

   ```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // one single thread - no race conditions between sequentially submitted tasks guaranteed

    Future task;

    task = executor.submit(() -> { // start increment
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // increment the counter
        }
    });
    ...

    task.cancel(true); // stop increment

    ...

    task = executor.submit(() -> { // start increment again
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // increment the counter
        }
    });
    ...
    task.cancel(true); // stop increment
   ```

Additional notes:

- If you need not just to increment counter, but to wait for a job to be ready to be executed, I'd suggest to use a BlockingQueue to communicate threads (Work/Job/Task Queue, Producer-Consumer patterns) (see, for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-blocking-queue).
- If you make blocking IO calls (on a socket, for example), you better use explicitly a thread and close() (called from another thread) as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/4426050/3319725. Set a volatile flag isClosing before to know that SocketException just happened is not an error, but just a side effect of the closing and it can be ignored.
- If you catch an InterruptedException, don't forget to restore the Thread.interrupted flag with Thread.currentThread().interrupt() if there is a chance that someone else can verify it later (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html)