# Restart app programmatically?

Tags: android

I need to restart the app programmatically. My launcher activity is called '**Login**' and after login, the main activity is called '**Main**'. From within the main activity I want to restart the app. So I have the following:

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

This will show the 'Login' activity, however when I press back I'm returned back to the previous activity.

Is there a better way to really restart the app?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Try below code**

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().
           getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

**And another thing before calling your second Activity call**

```
finish();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

call **finish()**

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Great, this really works