# How to reset/restart the app when onTrimMemory() method is called?

Tags: android, android-memory, android-background, android-os-handler

Currently I am handling `onTrimMethod(int level)` in my app with `ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE` and `ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL`. I get this callback easily with low end devices when my app is running in background and simultaneously I am playing games.

In that I put `Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);` to kill the app in background only so that when user taps on app (running in background), app will restart from launcher activity. I don't know it kills the app or not but when I open the app, first it **shows dialog with "Unfortunately, app has stopped"** and app does not restarts.

If I start the activity from this method, it will launch the application and bring it to foreground without any user interaction.

I tried some other ways too to kill the app. They are `System.exit(0);` and `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` but none of them are solving my problem.

So, what to write in `onTrimMethod()` or how to handle in other way so that when user opens the application (brings to foreground from background) it will start from the first activity?

Comment: Do you really want to do that? OnTrimMemory is more for releasing memory from caches and what not. It isn't a signal that the app should be restarted.

Comment: Yes I want to restart the app. I have cleared the cache but that does not stop app to be crashed when bringing it to foreground. So my app is like once user signs in, he/she can use it, and I keep session and other relavant info in memory. So if I clear the cache, I need user to start from login screen. I want to know how to do that.

Comment: I don't think it is a good solution. Of course OOM problems can be very difficult, but the solution is to get rid of any warnings under 'Analyse -> Inspect Code' and to use 'Run -> Profile' to find the problem. But this thread has some hacks for 'restarting' the app : [How do I programmatically restart an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-do-i-programmatically-restart-an-android-app)