# How to programmatically quit an android application and then reopen it?

Tags: android

I am doing an android application, and I'm trying to handle a restart method where the application needs to reset and delete its data saved in local. I've already tried the `System.exit(0)` method, but the application keeps running in backgroung. Instead, the thing I want to do is to completely close the application(also the application task) and then re-open it. Is there a way to do this or not?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you might post a notification that will open your app when the users opens it.

Comment: That's a good idea man, I will try and let u know if it works.

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-do-i-programmatically-restart-an-android-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I programmatically "restart" an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/how-do-i-programmatically-restart-an-android-app)

Comment: Also, Android 10 added some restrictions to only start activities only while your app is in foreground. This might also impact how your app is working after a possible "restart" https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to kill the app instead clear application data !! Try this ..

```
private void clearAppData() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData(); // note:it has a return value!
        } else {
            String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try ProcessPhoenix (https://github.com/JakeWharton/ProcessPhoenix/blob/master/README.md) although this is not intended for production code.

Comment: Link only answers are pretty bad since they are not useful anymore if the link breaks. Please consider adding more context to it, or moving it to a comment.

Comment: I am suggesting use of an open source library on github.com. If the link breaks then the library is likely not available anyway.