# what should I use to access network asynchronously in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, robospice

I implemented an `AsyncTask` in my app and encountered exceptions like `IllegalArgumentException`. I asked question on stack overflow somebody said I shouldn't use `AsyncTask` in apps for the following reasons.

- AsyncTasks don't follow Activity instances' life cycle
- Memory leak issue
- Progress of your task will be lost

I was recommended Robospice and also told consider this thread  [`AsyncTask` is not really the best tool to create network requests on Android. use RoboSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147992/693752)

Can anybody tell me what is best option to use access network asynchronously? What should I use `AsyncTask` or RoboSpice?

Comment: who said not to use AsyncTask? It is perfectly fine to use for anything that may take longer to execute.

Comment: You can also use a executor http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this guy at Google IO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE), using AsyncTask for networking is **not the way to go**.  He may give his presentation with an annoying & condescending tone, but nonetheless has some good points.

IMO the leading libraries to use are [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and [robospice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/).

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tried either of these yet.  While I like the API of android-async-http better, it seems like Robospice was more recently developed and supports better libraries.

I may end up rolling my own that extends `IntentService`.

Comment: thanks steve for your information. actually I know about robospice but don't know how to use it.

Comment: @Nilesh yeah I think it seems a bit heavy and confusing to get started with.  I may publish my `IntentService` + `ResultReceiver` if I think it's worth sharing.  Stay tuned.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

here is an Android Asynchronous Http Client library file to do these work.  Have a try.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 0):

I have been using AsyncTasks for a few projects and never had that problems. Nevertheless as Snicolas said in that post, is possible to had problems if you use AsyncTasks for **long running** operations (note the bold).

So if you're doing short ops, try AsyncTasks, otherwise I would give Robospice a try.

Comment: Thanks Shyish. suppose i have multilistview in that I fetch 200 records from rest web service at this condition can I use Robospice?

Answer (score 0):

an asyncTask instance just can use one time,if you want to execute the second request must call new () again

Answer (score 0):

I use AsyncTask in all my applications. No problem.

Example in fragment 
http://pastebin.com/EDZtKy3M

Example base for a custom implementation of CustomTask
http://pastebin.com/F18hRXr6