# AsyncTask status in Activity's onStop() state

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have started a `AsyncTask` to decode the contents in a file on a `Button` click. `AsyncTask` is running fine, now I pressed home button. `Activity` entered into `onStop()` state. Now what happens to my `AsyncTask`, Will it run or stop in this `onStop()` state?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531336/asynctask-wont-stop-even-when-the-activity-has-destroyed

Comment: It will continue to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activity stop will not make your async task to stop. Your async task will continue and if you have some reference of view in post execute it will cause exception.

You can also use `AsyncTaskLoader` instead.

Read about it:

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/loaders-versus-asynctask

Answer (score 1):

No it can't be. Your activity has been stopped your ***AsyncTask*** will continues. IF you want to stop it you have to cancel your AsyncTask.