# Android , does AsyncTask is running when press home button or switch from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can anyone explain me the behavior of `AsyncTask`, is `AsyncTask` running when we press the `back/home` button or we switch from `Activity A` to `Activity B`.

Comment: Yes, it is, unless it's canceled or the Activity from which it's bind is destroyed.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531336/asynctask-wont-stop-even-when-the-activity-has-destroyed

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowlege Asynktask require userInterface if you close your activity by pressing onBack than load asynk task is not possible but if you call another activity On onBack press than as a result onCreate method of Any Activity Which is load By onBack press you can call AsynkTask..
and  in your case suppoze you switch from  "activity A" to "activity B" than onCreate method of activity B you can call AsynkTask as well as before starting "activity B" you can prepare data for "activity B" and as a result of Asynktask in onPostExecute method  you can call "activity b" with data for "activity B".

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the back button:
Your asynctask's doInBackGround() will finish because it runs in a thread separate from the main UI thread; if for instance its task had been to upload a large file to a remote server it will complete that one.
But since your activity has been destroyed it will never be able to deliver its results to onPostExecute();