# Asynctask updates view even when my app is in background(home button pressed)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am running an AsyncTask in MainActivity and making it sleep for 10 seconds in the `doInBackground()` method. And in between (before the 10 seconds are over), I press the Home button and I am also updating the text in TextView in the `onPostExecute()` method of the AsyncTask. My AsyncTask is able to update the view successfully even though my app is in background.

I am not sure how that is possible, by the way, if I press the Back button, then I can see the `onDestroy()` method of the activity being called, but still there is no exception when the `onPostExecute()` method tries to update the TextView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView finalTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        finalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalTextView);

        AsyncTaskRunner task = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        task.execute("10", "11", "12");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("onDestroy", "ActivityDestroyed");
    }

    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
            try {
                int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0]) * 1000;

                Thread.sleep(time);
                resp = "Slept for " + params[0] + " seconds";
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }
            return resp;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
            finalTextView.setText(result);
            Log.e("onPostExecute", "" + result);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is designed so to work in background and publish result to UI thread, and when you press home button activity is not destroyed..

Comment: I have 1 answer which relevant to your problem. I think it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49571060/5381331

Answer (score 2):

Before jumping to any conclusion you should know how async task works

Go thorugh this answer which may solve half of your problem

One more thing like
Async task works on UI thread of the application
[what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652560/what-is-the-android-uithread-ui-thread)
 [AsyncTask won't stop even when the activity has destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531336/asynctask-wont-stop-even-when-the-activity-has-destroyed/13147992)

Go read the reference docs on AsyncTask to understand how the threads interact and which methods run on which thread.

[AsyncTask | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)